# Is there any good substitute for BuildURLFromExpression

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC ASP 1.0 , how can i acheive the functionality done by BuildURLFromExpression method ? basically i am trying to get image from Controller 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

return(new FileResult(pathtoimage, "image/jpeg"));

you can also do it with bytes to image, pdf etc

Comment: return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");